# metro ui css tile element-selected doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, tile, metro-ui-css

Visual Studio 2013, ASP.NET web form, metro UI CSS 3.0

I'm trying to create a tile element-selected that looked like the one in this site http://metroui.org.ua/tiles.html

```
<div class="tile bg-green fg-white element-selected" data-role="tile">
   <div class="tile-content iconic">
      <span class="icon mif-home"></span>
      <div class="tile-label"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

my code create a tile like this one above, with the tick icon checked, but when I press the tile, the tick icon doesn't uncheck as it should be !

The thing i want here is to create a tile that will display a tick icon when user click it, and will uncheck when user click it again.

Hope somebody can help me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I made the *select* and *deselect* work:

```
$("[data-role='tile']").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("element-selected")){
        $(this).removeClass("element-selected");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("element-selected");
    }
});
```

**[Here is the link to the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7bz6ncs/)**

Comment: use $(this).toggleClass("element-selected");

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I dont know why, the tile clik make a second click.

I use:

```
$('.class').mousedown(function(event) {$(this).toggleClass("selected")})
```

And it´s works.